# Android Studio - FileOutputStream clear file context

Tags: java, android-studio, file, fileoutputstream

I opened a file, and every time I want to write to it, it saves what I wrote the last time. How do I delete all the contents of the file?.

My code:

```
        String fileName = "MyFile";
        String content = "Hello from file";

        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I know that `Context.MODE_APPEND` is matters. What should i write insted?

Comment: Can you show the openFileOutput method.
Because normally you would just do:
new FileOutputStream(new File(entireFilePath));

Comment: I want to save it in the same file. this is the whole method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String fileName = "MyFile.txt";
String content = "Hello from file";

try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName, false);
    out.write(content.getBytes());
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Just create your FileOutputStream like this

Every time you open a new FileOutputStream it will start fresh again.
The old data will be overwritten / gone

The second argument of the FileOutputStream constructor is whether it should append or not. By setting it to false or passing no second argument at all it won't append